# Reducer is not updating state of component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I've been trying to get this to work all day but have not been able to find a solution from documentation or other posts so hopefully, someone will be able to help me out.

I have a component `transactions` that I call from within another component `dashboard.` When `transaction` loads it triggers an action that then triggers the reducer. I confirmed that the reducer has the payload I am looking for but for some reason does not cause `componentWillUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` to execute in the `transactions` component. It does cause `componentWillUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` in `dashboard` to get run, but when I check the props the data is not there. I've added some code that may be helpful, but does anyone have an idea of why my reducer is not triggering any lifecycle update methods in the `transactions` component? Thanks for the help!

=>Transactions.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getTransactionsFromMongo
} from "../../actions/transactionAction";

class Transactions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      transactions: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getTransactionsFromMongo();
  }

  render() {
    return <p>Hello world</p>;
  }
}

Transactions.propTypes = {
  getTransactionsFromMongo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  transactions: state.transactions
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getTransactionsFromMongo }
)(Transactions);
```

=> transactionReducer.js

```
import { GET_MONGO_TRANSACTIONS, UPDATE_TRANSACTION } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  transactions: "",
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MONGO_TRANSACTIONS:
      console.log("in get reducer");
      var tmp = JSON.stringify(action.payload);
      console.log(typeof(tmp));
      return {
        ...state,
        transactions: tmp
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

=>Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getAccounts, addAccount } from "../../actions/accountActions";

import Accounts from "./Accounts";
import Transactions from "./Transactions";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAccounts();
  }


  render() {

    dashboardContent = (<Transactions>Hello</Transactions>);

    return <div className="container">{dashboardContent}</div>;
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getAccounts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  addAccount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  transactions: state.transactions
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser, getAccounts, addAccount }
)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: are you sure this isn't working? What do you see if you move that `console.log(this.props)`  to the `render` method?

Comment: @sdotson it prints the props with transactions: undefined. If it updated the state correctly, would it not trigger one of the lifecycle methods first?

Comment: It seems everything works well, please leave a link to CodeSandBox re-production of your issue.

Comment: @AmerllicA should it not be calling a lifecycle method within transactions the component?

Comment: @AaronRotem, Even I cannot guess, your codes are well. I should debug it on a an online debugging run like CodeSandBox.

Comment: @AmerllicA I have never used CodeSandBox but I will try to get it up and running

Comment: Dear @AaronRotem, it is simple. just re-produce your project and reduce your codes to a tiny project and the least codes that have the same issue. do not put all of your project codes on the air.